# SageMathCloud Load Python script with argument

Tags: python-2.7, sage

I want to, inside a Sage worksheet, load a Python script that takes in a command line argument. So far, I have tried

```
    load("script.py") argument
    load("script.py" argument)
    run "script.py" argument
    etc....
```

I have also tried setting the cell to %run, %python, and %load, and none seem to be able to take in an argument in any form.

I know that I would be able to simply run it in a Jupyter notebook, but I'm looking for a way specifically inside a Sage worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is not (yet) implemented - see [this issue](https://github.com/sagemathinc/smc/issues/290).